# What is '$app/navigation' and how it is generated?

Tags: svelte, sveltekit

Following the procedure described in [Supabase.com Auth Helper Guide](https://supabase.com/docs/guides/auth/auth-helpers/sveltekit), I'm totally lost on finding out the solution for the error `Cannot find module '$app/navigation' or its corresponding type declarations.` when importing it in my `src\routes\+layout.svelte` like so:

```
import { invalidate } from '$app/navigation'
```

Comment: That is a type error, where is it from? Does it prevent the build?

Comment: you are right, its a type error, and it only showing up when used within <script lang='ts'>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The SvelteKit types are defined in the NPM module:

```
node_modules/@sveltejs/kit/types/ambient.d.ts
```

```js
declare module '$app/navigation' {
    import { BeforeNavigate, AfterNavigate } from '@sveltejs/kit';

    /**
     * If called when the page is being updated following a navigation (in `onMount` or `afterNavigate` or an action, for example), this disables SvelteKit's built-in scroll handling.
     * This is generally discouraged, since it breaks user expectations.
     */
    export function disableScrollHandling(): void;
    ...
```

If those definitions are not found, your configuration might be wrong or the project is not synchronized. Synchronization happens automatically when the dev server is running or when executing `svelte-kit sync`.

SvelteKit should generate a `tsconfig.json` and `ambient.d.ts` which references those types in a `.svelte-kit` directory.
Your main `tsconfig.json` should extend the generated file:

```json
{
    "extends": "./.svelte-kit/tsconfig.json",
    ...
}
```

Comment: thanks for this. adding into extends helps! well try if I can build and successfully deploy as well.

Answer (score 0):

Are you missing the " ' "?

```
import { invalidate } from '$app/navigation'
```

Comment: It's just a typo, the actual code have the "'". thanks